# Can a connection command be embedded in a psql script?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am running a script interactively to test it. The meta-command *\c* is not playing well with the standard sql commands: it seems to want to be run by itself. Here is what happens when it is run in the script

```
\set username steve

\c pubkey  :username

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO :username;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL sequences IN SCHEMA public TO :username;
```

Results:

```
invalid integer value "ALL" for connection option "port"
Previous connection kept
```

But if the "\c" command is run by itself then the subsequent *grant*'s are successful.   Is there a way to embed the "\c" connection commands in a psql script?

Comment: I guess that the variable `username` contains some spaces by mistake. the port would be the fourth argument of `\c`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  It does not have spaces: also consider that the "\c" command works when executed by itself.

Comment: Since you don't show the code that  sets `username`, I can say no more. But the error message is clear.

Comment: It seems psql interprets :username as user, "GRANT" as host and "ALL" as port. So the problem seems the separation of the commands. What are end of line chars in your file?

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis  This is on macOS and the line endings are `\cr` (not `\cr\lf`) or in hex '0x0a'

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe added the `\set username` info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that running in `psql` has different behavior than in a script itself: running the above from the command line using `-f` does work

```
psql postgres -f create_dbs.sql -a > db.out 2>&1
```

Whereas running the '\c` command from psql seems to need to be isolated.